# WebView.evaluateJavascript() not working obfuscated

Tags: android, webview, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to make use of WebView.evaluateJavascript() in WebView but as soon as I use Proguard to obfuscate, it no longer works.

I have some example code to illustrate what I am doing, in a service I create a WebView. I attach a custom WebChromeClient that logs all alerts:

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
{
    final private static String TAG = MyWebChromeClient.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.v(TAG, message);
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I attach this WebChromeClient

```
this.webView = new WebView(context)
this.webView.setWillNotDraw(true);
this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
this.webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
this.webView.loadUrl("");
this.webView.evaluateJavascript("alert('test')", new ValueCallback<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        @JavascriptInterface
                        public void onReceiveValue(String s)
                        {
                            Log.v("JSEvaluation",  s.toString());
                        }
                    });
```

While this works correctly when I am debugging with proguard on, it does not work without debugging and proguard on. Any idea what's causing this?

My proguard file is correct I think:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep @interface android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * { @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>; }
-keep class my.class.package.** { *; }
```

As you can see the classes that execute this are not obfuscated at all. Are there any rules needed to get WebView working correctly?

Comment: how does your proguard config look like?